# Sessão PHP e MySql

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho duas tabelas uma para login e senha e outra onde ficam os dados do usuário, como endereço, telefone, etc..

Após iniciar a sessão **gostaria que os dados exibidos na tela não fossem o do login e sim o nome da pessoa, com endereço telefone.**

O code da sessão é esse, estou usando duas tabela no mysql.

```
session_start();
$message="";
if(count($_POST)>0) {
    $conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("users",$conn);
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name='" .      
    $_POST["user_name"] . "' and password = '". $_POST["password"]."'");
    $row  = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    if(is_array($row)) {
         $_SESSION["user_id"] = $row[user_id];
         $_SESSION["user_name"] = $row[user_name];
    } else {
         $message = "Login e Senha Invalidos!";
    }
}
if(isset($_SESSION["user_id"])) {
     header("Location:painelcontrol.php");
}
?>
```

Answer (score 5):

Você precisa fazer um **Inner Join** para selecionar os dados da outra tabela levando em conta o código do usuário.

```
SELECT 
   LOGIN, 
   EMAIL, 
   SENHA, 
   NOME, 
   ENDEREÇO, 
   TELEFONE 
FROM 
   USERS
INNER JOIN
   USERS_ENDERECO ON USERS_ENDERECO.ID_USER = USERS.ID_USER
WHERE
   EMAIL = '$email'
AND
   SENHA = '$senha'
```

Após isso é só colocar em sessão:

`$_SESSION["ENDERECO"] = $row[endereco];`